# browserify does not import jQuery file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, browserify, es6-modules

I have this on my main.js

```
import './libs/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js';
import './libs/jquery/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js';
import {myModule} from './myModule.js';
```

It works on browser correctly (Chrome, Safari).

When I make the prod file with:

```
browserify js/main.js -d -o js/main-prod.js -t [ babelify --presets [ es2015 ] ]
```

I get this error in Chrome:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined         main-prod.js:2349
```

and this in Safari:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jQuery    jquery-ui.min:6
```

I do not know how to fix this problem. Since $ is defined I have tried adding jQuery to window after the import with:

```
import './libs/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js';
window.jQuery = (window.jQuery) ? window.jQuery : $;
import './libs/jquery/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js';
import {myModule} from './myModule.js';
```

But it does not work.

**Edit**

I give up on browserify and started to use [Rollup](https://rollupjs.org/). Since it is not a direct answer to my question I will let it open.

Comment: Can you try to require jquery?: `window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');`

Comment: @sk11z00 same problem. Also `require` does not work native on Chrome or Safari.

Comment: You install jquery with nodejs or download package from jquery site?

Comment: @sk11z00 It is downloaded from the jQuery site because I need it accessible over the internet while in development.

Comment: try to add `<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>` on html file or php.